# Fetch sharepoint list by its title

Tags: rest, sharepoint, spfx

I have created a field/list column in Sharepoint list called 'Negative_TC_Count', when I try to fetch using REST call it returns below error

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Tracker2023')/items?Negative_TC_Count&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$top=5000&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

Error:-

> <m:error
> xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
>   <m:code>-1,
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException</m:code> <m:message
> xml:lang="en-US">The field or property 'Negative_TC_Count' does not
> exist.</m:message> </m:error>

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?

Comment: The issue was with mismatch of internal names, had to go list settings and take the actual names from the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @RobWindsor, you have to use the `$select` in SharePoint REST API endpoint to select specific columns from your SharePoint list. Like:

```
<site-url>/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Tracker2023')/items?$select=Title,Negative_TC_Count&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$top=5000&$orderby=Created desc
```

Considering `Negative_TC_Count` is the correct internal name of your SharePoint list column.

Also, one important thing you have to consider while writing the SharePoint REST API request endpoint is you have to use the **internal names** of your SharePoint list columns.

Sometimes display name of columns and internal name of columns can be different when you use the special characters in column names while creating the columns.

You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use $select to specify the fields/columns you wish to retrieve. Try changing your request to:

```
_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Tracker2023')/items?$select=Negative_TC_Count&$expand=AttachmentFiles&$top=5000&$orderby=Created%20desc
```

See Use [OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests | Select fields to return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests#select-fields-to-return) for more information.